How does Windows decide when to automatically install updates?
I am trying to get a handle on how Windows 10, once having downloaded them, makes the decision to actually install updates.
I am looking back through the event logs of a Windows 10 (1607) installation relating to the WindowsUpdateClient source. The computer gets turned on only occasionally (maybe for several hours every week or two, sometimes more often, sometimes less often).
I can see 4 different possible events.

Started Downloading
Started Installing
Installation Success
Installation Failed.

I can a lot of "Started Downloading" events on 4/April, 17/May, 27/June, 10/July but no attempt to begin installation until 10/July
Then on 10/July and 28 / August it starts to attempt a few installations - not all of what it previously downloaded (only 9 out of over 20 downloads) - some succeeded but two failed. The fails were:

HP - Printer - 20.79.1.6738 (failed twice!)
2022 Security Update (KB5012170)

Then on 28/August, it attempted to redownload the 2 failed ones, the HP one 3 times(!) (all starting at 13:29:39 so I don't think it's 3 retries)
And there's been nothing in the Event log since for this source - but a user reported on 10/Sept that it was attempting and failing to install the HP Printer one again (in a loop), but though these attempts don't appear in the event log under WindowsUpdateClient
So what triggers Windows to start the actual installation of updates?
And how does it choose which updates to install - i.e. why wasn't installation attempted of the other updates that appeared in the event log as downloading? (Maybe the download didn't complete - the event log only mentions the Start of download).
And are there any other events I should be looking out for in the event log? e.g. something else that indicates attempts to install the updates, or that indicates that the download o the update has completed? I feel like I might be missing some information, e.g. those HP Printer updates I mentioned.
Edit
I have read that it might decide to start installation during "idle time" - however, I am not sure how this is defined. And are there other conditions that would set off the installation?

On earlier versions of Windows outside of configure 18 hours timeframe referred to as Activity Hours. How are you still getting updates on 1607 consider it went out of support 6 years ago. There have been zero cumulative updates for 6 years, the HP driver update, does not require a system reboot.  The driver failing to install will have to be diagnosed separate from the secure boot update, which is failing, likely due to the incorrect size of the WinRE partition which is easaily resolved here

@Ramhound - Seem to be getting a cumulative update every month (KB5035855, KB5037763, KB5039214, etc.) - also updated versions of 'Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool' (KB890830) v5.125, 5.126, 5.127, etc.  as well as updates to .NET framework and that HP printer one of course.

@Ramhound "On earlier versions of Windows outside of configure 18 hours timeframe referred to as Activity Hours" - I thought this was just the time outside of which a reboot would be performed, whereas I'm talking about the update themselves.

You specifically asked when Windows would install the updates, the answer to that question, is outside of your activity hours. Windows 10 1607 absolutely is not receiving cumulative updates in 2024. KB5035855 was released in 2016. .NET Framework has its own support timeline, but the version that’s supported on 1607, is not receiving security updates in 2024 I really hope your not intentionally keeping an insecure Windows installation accessible to the internet.

@Ramhound - I may be misunderstanding something completely then - the name given to KB5035855 is "2024-03 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1607 for x64-based Systems" - and a quick google search points to: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/march-12-2024-kb5035855-os-build-14393-6796-6f2b7253-4f2d-49e9-aef8-c32d0b708a2f

That update was released for Windows Server 2016 which would still be supported. When I searched for KB5035855 I received results which suggested there was content from 2016. Windows Updates are still regularly checked and downloaded, and automatic restarts, happen outside of the define 18 hours of actively hours.

Automatic restarts I accept, but are you sure about the actual updates? Active hours on the device I am checking are from 08:00 - 17:00, but according to the event logs, updates began installing at around 12:00 on some of the days., and downloads appear like they are happening at any time (usually soon after the device is booted up).

Outside of a corporate environment, in a home environment, Windows Update will check for updates on a routine basis. It will install those updates based on how the system is configured, and will finish the installation of those updates, by performing a automated reboot

There are 2 main systems in Windows that work for the Windows Update system.
Windows Update Service
Windows Update uses a set of services to install the updates and maintain its health. The health mechanism will check if Windows Update is still setup the way it is supposed to be, and will attempt to fix it if this is not the case.
This is how the service can enable itself again if you stop or disable it.
The windows Update Service will perform all the actions for downloading, installing and rebooting the system, but it will not start this by itself. This is the executing component only.
Scheduling when the events happen
Windows Update uses Scheduled Tasks to plan when the next action is to take place. 
The scheduled tasks are located at: Library\Microsoft\Windows Update.
There will be a task: scheduled start which will have multiple triggers. This task will be scheduled regularly and initiate the Windows Update service to do a series of checks.
This is a list of what the Windows Update checks are:

Check/refresh the Group Policy settings
Check if there are new updates
Download new updates if available
Install updates if set to do so automatically
Check if a restart is pending
If pending restart, check if allowed to do, or if the user needs to grand permission
If user rescheduled the restart, reschedule the scheduled task.
Check if a certain time has passed and user has ignored a restart, restart anyway.

The GPO check is actually performed using a second scheduled task.
